# Not able to draw text on top or arc in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have drawn a custom arc using the draw arc method of the canvas library, now I want to write some text on top of this arc using TextPainter but when I paint the text on canvas I do not see anything. I just know the arc is drawn, and the text is invisible.

Is there some concept of Z-index or layering which I have to give to text paint to draw on top of the arc?

Below is my sample code

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChartPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    print(size.width);
    print(size.height);
    final Paint paint = new Paint()..color = Colors.blue;
    // Draw a circle that circumscribes the arrow.
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = 50.0;
    paint.isAntiAlias = true;
    //canvas.drawCircle(new Offset(centerX, centerY), r, paint);
    canvas.drawArc(new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height), 0.0,
        -math.pi / 4, false, paint);
    paint.color = Colors.orange;
    canvas.drawArc(new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height),
        -math.pi / 4, -math.pi / 4, false, paint);
    paint.color = Colors.green;
    canvas.drawArc(new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height),
        -math.pi / 2, -math.pi / 4, false, paint);
    paint.color = Colors.purple;
    canvas.drawArc(new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height),
        -math.pi * 3 / 4, -math.pi / 4, false, paint);

        TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24.0,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto'), text: "Ajay Singh");
    TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
        text: span, textAlign: TextAlign.left);
    tp.layout();
    tp.paint(canvas, new Offset(100.0, 100.0));

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(ChartPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking at verbose logs i found that setting TextDirection is mandator to paint the text i resolved this issue using TextDirection